# How can I fix Expression Error in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi

I am having a problem with the scheduled refresh in Power Bi Service.

I have set up a scheduled refresh a couple of weeks back and I have noticed that I am getting the below error:

Data source error: Expression. Error: We cannot convert the value <con» null to type Text. </eco, The exception was
aised by the IDataReader interface, Please review the error message and provider documentation for urther information and corrective action. Table: New Training
Cluster URI
Activity ID:
Request ID:
Time: try
WABI-US-EAST2-C-PRIMARY-redirectanalysis.windows.net
ed76a994-8606-452-a038-915db7e4a84F
2262697-9379-4022-46-18a79dca34bc
2028-04-17 13:06:097

I have manually refreshed the dashboard in Power BI Desktop and I am not getting the above error.

I am ensure as how to fix the error.

Thank you

I have manually refreshed the dashboard in Power BI Desktop and    I am not getting the error.